# Evolution & EWS Calendar

Tags: linux, calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to view my main calendar using Evolution 3.10.3 and the EWS plugin.

I can create a new calendar when doing New->Calendar->Select my Exchange account->input a name. I can see the calendar created when using outlook.

However I cant find a way to get the main calendar under evolution.

If anybody was able to make it work, help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself in the same situation. Then I re-setup the account and checked the "Automatically synchronize remote mail locally" on the Receiving Options tab and after that my calendar and tasks downloaded automatically.

Comment: I didn't even have to re-setup the account.  I just went into `Receiving Options` and checked "Synchronize remote mail locally in all folders" (I presume the exact name of the option has changed since 2014)